# Intuition behind Nekreasov's instanton partition function. What do the partitions represent exactly?

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, instantons

I am struggling to understand many things behind Nekrasov's solution. Firstly I want to understand the following

1. In this theory, $a$ represents VEVs the Higgs scalar. So, is the gauge field of the hyper broken? The theory is broken from $SU(N)$ to what?

and then

2. How are the Young diagrams related to the point like $k$-instantons? And why do we sum over these Young diagrams? Is there an intuitive way to understand it?

A readable reference is the Master thesis *A Pedagogical Introduction to
the AGT Conjecture* by Robert J.
Rodger, chapter 3. ([PDF](http://web.science.uu.nl/itf/Teaching/2013/R.J.Rodger.pdf))

Comment: Tip: Consider adding references and context in order to get useful and focused answers.

Comment: I did, but I don't think it will be of any help. Only someone working on this field can actually help (I think). Let's see.

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/33719/